# Use javascript array reduce given n inputs to yield m outputs

Tags: javascript, reduce, declarative

I have a series of points that I want to change into a series of lines.

this is an example of what I want to the code do

```
[p1, p2, p3] -> [line1, line2]
```

each loop:

```
(p1, p2) -> line
(p2, p3) -> line
```

The standard way to do this is:

```js
const triangle = [[0,0], [0,1], [1,2]]

const lines = []
for (let i = 1; i < triangle.length; ++i) {
  const slope = findSlopeFromPoints(...triangle[i - 1], ...triangle[i])
  const yIntercept = findYIntercept(...triangle[i], slope)
  lines.push({
    slope,
    yIntercept
  })
}
```

This is the closes I can get using `Array.prototype.reduce`. But it feels much harder to reason about

```
const initial = {
  array: [], // actual returned array we care about
  lastPoint: null // "triangle[i - 1]"
}
const linesR = triangle.reduce( (lines, point) => {
  if (lines.lastPoint === null)
    return { 
      ...lines, 
      lastPoint: point 
    }
  else {
    const slope = findSlopeFromPoints(...lines.lastPoint, ...point)
    const yIntercept = findYIntercept(...point, slope)
    lines.array.push({
      slope,
      yIntercept
    })
    lines.lastPoint = point
    return lines

  }
}, initial )
```

In short, is there a better way to use reduce to combine `N` inputs into `N - 1` outputs?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please add a wanted result and the data structure.

Comment: apologies, I updated the question

Comment: The standard functional technique to approach this problem would be to `zip` the list with itself shifted by an offset of 1. (In Haskell, `zipWith makeLine points (tail points)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use the `currentIndex` argument to apply an offset. Your callback function receives several more arguments<sup>1</sup> than you're using:

```
[{x:0, y:0}, {x:0, y:1}, {x:1, y:2}].reduce((lines, point, currentIndex, source) => {
  currentIndex < source.length -1 && lines.push({
    from: point,
    to: source[currentIndex + 1]
  }); 
  return lines;     
}, []);
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>See `Array.prototype.reduce()` for more info.</sub>

Comment: if points are defined outside the array, i might prefer https://jsfiddle.net/qxdsgddu/

Comment: @seveibar sure, but If we're going that far, I'd say skip the array methods altogether and just loop. We're not getting much lift from `reduce()` anyway... much less from copying a subset of the array for processing. At any rate, this is just a conceptual demo.